# Is there a way to parse out information from a xcom_pull in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

So what I'm working with is I have a DAG that has specific information that is being passed through tasks, everything is working as it should. The file needs to be stored into a `reports/` folder for the following tasks to work correctly. I'm calling the actual name of the report through a `xcom_pull` but I also want to parse out information from this `xcom_pull` in order to capture the unique filename itself to use later on in other tasks. I have a task later on that inserts this filename into the csv file, but I need it to match the filename itself so its a 1:1 match.

I want to parse out information of a `xcom_pull` option and I'm having issues doing so. The example I have is below:

```
    report_filename = "reports/{}_{}".format('report_example', str(uuid.uuid1()))
    get_report = GoogleCampaignManagerDownloadReportOperator(
        task_id="get_report",
        profile_id=1234,
        api_version=1234,
        bucket_name=test_bucket,
        report_name=report_filename,
        report_id=report_id,
        file_id=file_id,
    )
    
    report_filename_test = xcom_pull(get_report, 'report_name')
    sanitize_report = SanitizeReportOperator(
        task_id='sanitize_report',
        dest_bucket=test_bucket,
        dest_object=report_filename_test,
        shared_object=str(report_filename_test).replace('reports/', ''),
        append_timestamp=True,
        append_filename=True
    )
```

As of right now the `xcom_pull` pulls down the following:

```
reports/report_example_b3413b62-cc8a-11ec-bded-52e9ae62e477.csv.gz
```

However, I want to have another `xcom_pull` that will only pull the following:

```
report_example_b3413b62-cc8a-11ec-bded-52e9ae62e477.csv.gz
```

I have tried converting `report_filename_test` to a string and using the replace function, so for example:

```
new_test = str(report_filename_test).replace('reports/', '')
```

But when attempting this, it makes the `new_test` converting into a `NULL` format or ignores it completely and saves the file later on into a `reports/` folder.

I have also tried passing the `report_filename` into a list and grabbing the first iteration and grabbing the first iteration, but with how Airflow works from task to task, it creates a new filename with a different uuid each time, which is not what I'm aiming to have done. I have also tried doing a PythonOperator option to create a function specifically to name the file and be called later on throughout the DAG but have not had any luck with this either.

Is there a way to do this where you can parse out the information from a `xcom_pull` or another way to make this work? The end goal is to essentially have a file name with a specific uuid that I can pass through into the csv file and rename the file to the same specific uuid that is being built without the folder name in front.

I'm just looking to have a unique filename be passed through multiple tasks that is the exact same each time with a uuid format. I'm running out of ideas of how to make this work and have been stuck on this for almost two weeks now.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `report_filename_test`?  `xcom_pull` should be used within tasks.   But if you try to use the value outside of task, it is just `report_filename_test = report_filename`.  it is not clear to me what you want to pass and what to do with it.

Comment: @Emma I updated the above with the next task that is being utilized. Essentially what I'm trying to accomplish is to utilize the `report_filename` but without the `reports/` folder structure in the naming convention to then be inserted into a csv file of the exact `filename` that it's utilizing throughout the DAG. Hopefully that makes sense, let me know if it doesn't and I can try to explain better.

Comment: Shouldn't `str(report_filename_test).replace('reports/', '')` just be `report_filename.replace('reports/', '')`, no need to use xcom?  Are you overwriting this value within `GoogleCampaignManagerDownloadReportOperator`?

Comment: If I do that then it will call the `report_filename` again which will then result in a different uuid format which isn't what I'm aiming for. I'm looking to have the same uuid passed through all tasks and rename the filename with that specific uuid to be able to match all records to a single filename 1:1 ratio if that makes sense

Comment: no.  `report_filename` has evaluated value.  so when you reference the `report_filename` later in the code, you won't get the different value.

Comment: You can try this code "parser.parse(string.replace('_plus_', '+').replace("_", ":"))" just edit the character and variable you use.

Comment: @Emma I tried what you stated and ended up with two different uuids across two different DAG tasks, which isn't unique of what I'm aiming for.

Comment: hmm, I don't see why.  Maybe if you can post the latest code, I could be able to spot something.